# Wordpress Gutenberg - nesting child elements

Tags: wordpress-gutenberg

I'm new to reactjs so I'm struggling a bit with trying to add a custom block to the gutenberg editor. The block itself is displaying, but is giving an error "This block has encountered an error and cannot be previewed".

Here's the code I've got so far

```
edit: function() {
        var tb = element.createElement('input', { placeholder: 'Enter a url', type: 'text' },
            [element.createElement(
                'p',
                { style: blockStyle },
                'Child 1'
            )]
        );
        return tb;

    },
```

I'm trying to get a text control and a label to display like this

```
<input type='text' name='mytb' />
<label for="mytb">My Label</label>
```

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

In your code, you have put the paragraph element as a descendant of input, this is not possible, so you are getting the error.

It should be:

```
 var tb = element.createElement('input', { placeholder: 'Enter a url', type: 'text' }),
          element.createElement( 'p', { style: blockStyle }, Child 1');
return tb;
```

Comment: Thanks. this code still doesn't work for me.  Still showing as the same error

Comment: I've edited so that it falls along the lines of how you have defined `createElement` and removed the incorrect brace placement.

Answer (score 0):

```
var tb = [element.createElement( 'input', { placeholder: 'Enter a url', type: 'text' } ),
         element.createElement( 'p', {}, 'Child 1' )];
return tb;
```

I have fixed some code issues and removed your blockStyle. You need to make sure that you have defined this variable.